# How using drawable-hdpi, mdpi... etc. affects performance of drawing ImageViews

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

Working on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338351/how-to-improve-the-performance-of-viewflipper-viewanimator) I noticed a difference in performance depending on where I put my assets. Counter-intuitively, ImageViews get drawn faster when I move my assets to drawable-hdpi when testing on a mdpi device (scaling factor of 1).

Are there any general rules to this? I'm not sure this can be applied to other cases because I've extended layouts and widgets here and there.

Answer (score -1):

[This will clear you hdpi-ldpi doubt.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263265/drawable-hdpi-drawable-mdpi-drawable-ldpi-android)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I was looking for something more specific, though.