# Possible to jump straight to second view in ViewAnimator

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view

I have a `ViewAnimator` (`ViewSwitcher` to be precise) with fade in/out animations associated to it and two `Views` which I transition between using the `ViewAnimator.showNext()` and `ViewAnimator.showPrevious()` methods.

There is a requirement in my app where sometimes I need to start straight from the second `View`, without showing a fade animation in going from the first `View` to the second. Anyone know if there is a straightforward way to accomplish this without having to mess around with the in/out animations associated to my `ViewAnimator`?

> **Note:** I have tried calling `ViewAnimator.setDisplayedChild(1)` but that also animates the transition.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I looked around and waited for a response but I'm guessing it's not possible. So, in the absence of a better solution, set your `ViewAnimator`'s in/out animations to null when you want to jump straight to a particular child `View` of your `ViewAnimator`, as follows:

```
myViewAnimator.setInAnimation(null);
myViewAnimator.setOutAnimation(null);
myViewAnimator.setDisplayedChild(childIndex);
```

If anyone knows a better way - rather than playing with the `ViewAnimator`'s in/out animations - please share!

Comment: I think this is the only way, it is a shame really.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in function to do that, but you can add this function, which does the job:

```
public static void setDisplayedChildNoAnim(ViewAnimator viewAnimator, int whichChild) {
    Animation inAnimation = viewAnimator.getInAnimation();
    Animation outAnimation = viewAnimator.getOutAnimation();
    viewAnimator.setInAnimation(null);
    viewAnimator.setOutAnimation(null);
    viewAnimator.setDisplayedChild(whichChild);
    viewAnimator.setInAnimation(inAnimation);
    viewAnimator.setOutAnimation(outAnimation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more comprehensive way, which let you choose either an id or a view, and with/without animation:

```
fun ViewAnimator.setViewToSwitchTo(viewToSwitchTo: View, animate: Boolean = true): Boolean {
    if (currentView === viewToSwitchTo)
        return false
    for (i in 0 until childCount) {
        if (getChildAt(i) !== viewToSwitchTo)
            continue
        if (animate)
            displayedChild = i
        else {
            val outAnimation = this.outAnimation
            val inAnimation = this.inAnimation
            this.inAnimation = null
            this.outAnimation = null
            displayedChild = i
            this.inAnimation = inAnimation
            this.outAnimation = outAnimation
        }
        return true
    }
    return false
}

fun ViewAnimator.setViewToSwitchTo(@IdRes viewIdToSwitchTo: Int, animate: Boolean = true): Boolean {
    if (currentView.id == viewIdToSwitchTo)
        return false
    for (i in 0 until childCount) {
        if (getChildAt(i).id != viewIdToSwitchTo)
            continue
        if (animate)
            displayedChild = i
        else {
            val outAnimation = this.outAnimation
            val inAnimation = this.inAnimation
            this.inAnimation = null
            this.outAnimation = null
            displayedChild = i
            this.inAnimation = inAnimation
            this.outAnimation = outAnimation
        }
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Example of usage:

```
viewSwitcher.setViewToSwitchTo(someView,false)
```