# Scene transition is lagging out ViewFlipper

Tags: java, android, transition, scene, viewflipper

I have a `ViewFlipper` that basically resembles somebody deleting and typing text (i.e. deleting the word that is currently there and typing something else), and on the same activity I have a floating action button that, when pressed, brings up some icons that allows the user to click to go to certain websites (GitHub link, YouTube link, Instagram link, etc.). However, when the floating action button is pressed, it uses an `AutoTransition` (fading in, out) to transition to the next `Scene` (the clickable icons). This transition is lagging out my `ViewFlipper` (it is making the `ViewFlipper` pause for a little and then "type" really quickly.

Some possible issues:

1. The `ViewFlipper` text uses the `Html.fromHtml()` to format the text (I need part of the text to be bold and different colors. To fix this, I could use a faster way to render text. Does anybody have any suggestions for this?
2. The transition between the `Scene`s could also be too slow. However, I don't know a way around this.

So far, I've tried disabling the `AutoTransition`, which works, but it makes the button usage really awkward and uncomfortable. I've tried searching for this problem but I couldn't find anything.

Here is my code for the `ViewFlipper`:

```
public void inflateViewFlipper(String boldedName, String finalPhrase, String... words) {
    if (words.length == 0) return;
    ViewFlipper vf = findViewById(R.id.heading_flipper);
    vf.removeAllViews();
    // Vowels, determining whether to use "a" or "an":
    Set<Character> vowels = new HashSet<>();
    vowels.add('a');
    vowels.add('e');
    vowels.add('i');
    vowels.add('o');
    vowels.add('u');
    vowels.add('A');
    vowels.add('E');
    vowels.add('I');
    vowels.add('O');
    vowels.add('U');
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        String word = words[i];
        boolean an = vowels.contains(word.charAt(0));
        String first = "<b>" + boldedName + "</b>\nis a" + (an ? "n" : "") + "<br>" +
                "<font color=\"#fafafa\">︳</font><i>" + word + "</i>︳&#8202<br>" + finalPhrase;
        String second = "<b>" + boldedName + "</b>\nis a" + (an ? "n" : "") + "<br>" +
                "<font color=\"#fafafa\">︳</font><i>" + word +
                "</i><font color=\"#fafafa\">︳&#8202</font><br>" + finalPhrase;
        if (i > 0) {
            // "Typing" the adjective:
            for (int j = 0; j <= word.length(); j++) {
                String cut = word.substring(0, j);
                String newText = "<b>" + boldedName + "</b>\nis a" + (an ? "n" : "") + "<br>" +
                        "<font color=\"#fafafa\">︳</font><i>"
                        + cut + "</i>︳&#8202<br>" + finalPhrase;
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(newText, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
                tv.setTextSize(30);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                vf.addView(tv);
            }
        }
        // Wait for a few seconds, cursor flashing to represent real cursors:
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(first, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
                tv.setTextSize(30);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                vf.addView(tv);
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(second, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
                tv.setTextSize(30);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                vf.addView(tv);
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(first, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
            tv.setTextSize(30);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            vf.addView(tv);
        }
        for (int j = word.length(); j > 0; j--) {
            String cut = word.substring(0, j);
            String newText = "<b>" + boldedName + "</b>\nis a" + (an ? "n" : "") + "<br>" +
                    "<font color=\"#fafafa\">︳</font><i>" +
                    cut + "</i>︳&#8202<br>" + finalPhrase;
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(newText, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
            tv.setTextSize(30);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            vf.addView(tv);
        }
        if (i == words.length - 1) {
            // "Deleting" the text:
            word = words[0];
            an = vowels.contains(word.charAt(0));
            for (int j = 0; j <= word.length(); j++) {
                String cut = word.substring(0, j);
                String newText = "<b>" + boldedName + "</b>\nis a" + (an ? "n" : "") + "<br>" +
                        "<font color=\"#fafafa\">︳</font><i>"
                        + cut + "</i>︳&#8202<br>" + finalPhrase;
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(newText, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
                tv.setTextSize(30);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                vf.addView(tv);
            }
        }
    }
    // Starting the ViewFlipper:
    vf.onFinishTemporaryDetach();
    vf.invalidate();
    vf.showNext();
    vf.setFlipInterval(10);
    vf.startFlipping();
}
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is type a list of adjectives to represent what something is, like:
`Noun <-(bolded) is a(n) (insert adjective) <-(italicized)(text cursor) (Noun)`. For example, "**My Company** is an *amazing* messaging service".

My `Scene` transition is just an `AutoTransition`, nothing fancy:

```
showPopup.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    TransitionManager.go(socialMedia);
    // Switching the buttons:
    showPopup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    closePopup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
});
```

Thanks to anybody who can help!

EDIT - I have now tried using an answer from [How to improve the performance of ViewFlipper/ViewAnimator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338351/how-to-improve-the-performance-of-viewflipper-viewanimator), which was using `android:measureAllChildren="false"`. This solves the lagging issue, but now when I use the animation, it sometimes makes the entire `ViewFlipper` flash on and then off again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay! After a few days of scrounging around, I solved my problem. First, I used `android:measureAllChildren="false"` to solve the `ViewFlipper` lagging issues. After that, instead of using the Android built-in `AutoTransition` to transition between `Scene`s, I created my own `FadeIn` and `FadeOut` animations, and used `FrameLayout.startAnimation(Animation);` to animate. This helped me both control the animation time and stop the lag.